# Cube gets a little bigger when i draw it again. (Canvas, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```js
//Selectors
canvas = document.querySelector('.canvas');
canvas.setAttribute("tabindex", 0);
canvas.focus();
pointerImg = document.querySelector('.pointer');


//Variables
const pi = Math.PI;
const c = canvas.getContext('2d');
var grid = {
    'x':60,
    'y':20,
    'size':20,
}
var pointerValues = {
    37: {'x':-1, 'y':0},
    38: {'x':0, 'y':-1},
    39: {'x':1, 'y':0},
    40: {'x':0, 'y':1},
}


//Event Listeners
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    //init();
})


var cells = [];
for(let i=0;i<grid.x;i++) {
    cells[i] = new Array(grid.y);
}


//Functions
function init() {
    resizeGrid();
    initCells();

}
init();

function update(){
    requestAnimationFrame(update)

}
update();


function Cell(x, y, size) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.color = 'white';

    this.update = function() {
        this.draw();
    }

    this.draw = function() {
        c.beginPath();
        c.rect(this.x*this.size, this.y*this.size, this.size, this.size);
        c.strokeStyle = 'black';
        c.stroke();
        c.fillStyle=this.color; c.fill();
        c.closePath();
    }

    this.resetCell = function() {
        c.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
        this.update();
    }
}



function resizeGrid() {
    let windowX = window.innerWidth;
    windowX -= windowX*0.1;
    grid.size = windowX/grid.x;
    let canvasX = windowX, canvasY = grid.y * grid.size;
    canvas.width = canvasX;
    canvas.height = canvasY;

}


function initCells() {
    cells = [];
    for(let i=0;i<grid.x;i++) {
        cells[i] = new Array(grid.y);
    }


    for(let i=0;i<grid.x;i++) {
        for(let j=0;j<grid.y;j++) {
            cells[i][j] = new Cell(i, j, grid.size);
            cells[i][j].update();
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/main.css">
    
        <div style="display:none;">
            <img class='pointer' src="assets/img/pointer.svg">
        </div>

        <div class='nav'>

        </div>
    
    </head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="content">
            <canvas class='canvas'></canvas>
        </div>

        <script src='assets/js/canvas.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

```
function Cell(x, y, size) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.size = size;
  this.color = 'white';

  this.update = function () {
    this.draw();
  }

  this.draw = function () {
    c.beginPath();
    c.rect(this.x * this.size, this.y * this.size, this.size, this.size);
    c.strokeStyle = 'black';
    c.stroke();
    c.fillStyle = this.color;
    c.fill();
    c.closePath();
  }

  this.resetCell = function () {
    c.clearRect(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
    this.update();
  }
```

This is my code for a single cell in a grid. After I draw it a single time, when I call resetCell(), it draws the cell just a little bit bigger.

[image]

In this picture, I call Update for the very first cell and it becomes a tiny bit bigger than the rest.

I've tried pretty much everything but nothing seems to work.

Also can someone recommend better way to draw and control grid.
I need it to demonstrate BFS algorithm.

Comment: whats `grid.size`? did you mean `this.size`?

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: They are the same thing, i changed it to grid.size for debugging but it did not work.
Both of them result in tiny bit bigger cell when updating

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### You were tricked by the thickness of the border

The border has a thickness, which is easy to forget. If you draw a box which is X wide, its left and right border are *in addition* to the width of X.

So if you do NOT fill the interior, you get this nice appearance (left), but if you FILL, you get this ugly appearance (right).

[image]

When you draw a grid of these squares, each one covers over the right-hand and bottom sides of previous squares, so that it is not obvious what is happening.

Unless you redraw one that is not the last of the list, as I have done here (bottom-middle). Then it becomes obvious that something is wrong.

[image]

Here is the code to reproduce the above figures, and below I recommend a solution.

```js
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

// With NO fill, it looks fine
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(40, 40, 40, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(80, 80, 40, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();

// With white fill, the inner half of each box gets covered up by the white fill.
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(140, 40, 40, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="white"; 
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(180, 80, 40, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="white"; 
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

// Make Grid. This part looks OK initially.
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(240, 40, 40, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="white"; 
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(240, 80, 40, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="white"; 
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(280, 40, 40, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="white"; 
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(280, 80, 40, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="white"; 
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(320, 40, 40, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="white"; 
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(320, 80, 40, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="white"; 
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();

// Redraw one: this will look messed up.
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(280, 80, 40, 40);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle="white"; 
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="400" height="150" ></canvas>



</body>
</html>
```

#### Solution 1. Don't fill the interiors

This is the neatest solution, if you can get away with it, and it works regardless of any (non-zero) border thickness.

#### Solution 2. Shrink the width to allow for border thickness

This is complicated because you need to manually set the border thickness, and realise that it is in addition to the numerical values you specify for the rectangle's size.

Look at this messy business at CSS-tricks, even when they are trying to make borders interesting! https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border/

[image]